# Adding item to Dictionary returns System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code below:

```
List<string> group = new List<string>();
List<int> groupInNumber = new List<int>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dicMyMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dictionary<string, int[]> a = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
Dictionary<string, string[]> b = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

private void SetData(out ExpandableListViewAdapter mAdapter)
    {
        int[] currentStatus = a["currentStatus"];
        string[] statusDesc = b["description"];
        int[] ticketID = a["ticketID"];

        foreach (int s in currentStatus)
        {
            if (s == 1)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[0]);
            }
            else if (s == 2)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[1]);
            }
            else if (s == 3)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[2]);
            }
            else if (s == 4)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[3]);
            }
            else if (s == 5)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[4]);
            }
            else if (s == 6)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[5]);
            }
            else if (s == 7)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[6]);
            }
            else if (s == 8)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[7]);
            }
            else if (s == 9)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[8]);
            }
            else if (s == 10)
            {
                group.Add(statusDesc[9]);
            }
        }

        for (int p = 0; p <= ticketID.Count(); p++)
        {
            groupInNumber.Add(ticketID[p]);
        }

        List<string> ticket = new List<string>();
        for (int z = 0; z <= ticketID.Count(); z++)
        {
            string tix = ticketID[z].ToString();
            ticket.Add(tix);
            dicMyMap.Add(groupInNumber[z].ToString(), ticket);
            ticket.Remove(tix);
        }

        mAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, group, dicMyMap);
    }
```

The error occurs here, `groupInNumber.Add(ticketID[p]);` What I don't understand is why the index is outside the bounds when `0` should be referring to the first value inside the array. I tried counting the items in `int[] ticketID = a["ticketID"];`, isn't null, returned `39` (number of items in the array).

Comment: You might take a look to the `switch` statement.

Comment: Out of context.. That `else-if` ladder can be replaced with `switch`

Comment: Because z <= ticketID.Count() is wrong. Use z < ticketID.Count()

Comment: For performance, use `ticketID.Length` instead of `ticketID.Count()`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I totally didn't notice that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
for (int p = 0; p <= ticketID.Count(); p++)
{
    groupInNumber.Add(ticketID[p]);
}
```

It should be:

```
for (int p = 0; p < ticketID.Count(); p++)
```

You're iteration goes 1 index too far.   `0...9`   are `10` items.. so create a for loop  to `0..count-1`   so it should be `p < ticketID.Count()`

**This also applies to the other `for` loops**

---

*Offtopic:*

since `ticketID` is an `Array` you also could use the `Length` property.

```
for (int p = 0; p < ticketID.Length; p++)
```

---

Your `groupInNumber` is a `List<int>`. The List class also has an `AddRange()` method:

So this `for` loop...

```
for (int p = 0; p <= ticketID.Count(); p++)
{
    groupInNumber.Add(ticketID[p]);
}
```

...can be replaced with:

```
groupInNumber.AddRange(ticketID);
```